# Is the object that comes back as a result of a database query, an array or hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rails-activerecord

Was wondering what kind of form an object comes back when a query is returned from the database.

For example:

```
@Users = User.all
```

I'm thinking that when the all method queries all the users from the database, it comes back as an array since the each method is used eventually in the view.

But when I take a look in the console, the returned object seems like a hash but has the square brackets so I was wondering what the object comes back as.

How the console displays the returned object:

```
[#<User id: 1, email: "example@gmail.com"...>]>
```

Comment: `User.all.class.name`? `#<User id: ...>` is the result of standard AR `#to_s` call.

Comment: "is it an array or hash" - neither. It is a collection-like object (or array-like), which contains your model objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

It comes back as what rails calls an active record relation. It has most of the methods available to an array available to it, and has access to specific methods that retrieve records from the database far faster than standard queries, see 'where'.

Comment: So the each method on the active record relation object is different than the each method on Array objects per se.

Comment: @Robert `each` is a method of `Enumerator` class.

Comment: @Deep: MANY objects have `each` method. Array has its own. And `ActiveRecord::Relation#each` is delegated to that of the array. Enumerator is not used here.

Comment: @Deep hmmm so both the ActiveRecord_relation object and Array object inherits? from the Enumerator class so both object are able to use the each method? I thought the each method is pretty much used only for an array.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev So the each method which the ActiveRecord_relation has is different from the one the Array object has. And the each method for the Active Record_relation pretty much work exactly like an each method used for an Array, correct?

Comment: @Robert: these two "each" methods are actually the same and only method, `Array#each`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ok thanks!! so the ActiveRecord_relation is an array like object which has the each method and it can be used in the view to loop through the item within the array like object.

Comment: @Robert: yep, pretty much that.